# Compare/find a list in another list's nested lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I have a few lists called `find`. I want to know if these `find` are part of `full_list`. Lists `find 1-4` are part of `full_list` while lists `find 5-7` are not.

The example below returns `"Yes"`.

```
find1 = [[1, 1]]
find2 = [[1, 1], [2, 2]]
find3 = [[1, 1], [3, 3]]
find4 = [[4, 4], [2, 2], [3, 3]]

find5 = [[1, 0]]
find6 = [[1, 1], [2, 0]]
find7 = [[1, 1], [3, 0]]

full_list = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]]

if find2[0] in full_list and find2[1] in full_list:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Because `len(find2) != len(find4)`, the current `if` statement is very clumsy and almost useless.

How to make this work in a more universal way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `all()` with a generator which returns a `True` if everything is a truthy or `False`:

```
if all(x in full_list for x in find2):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")

# => prints Yes
```

This one is generic, just need to change `find2` to any list you need to check with `full_list`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
set1 = set(find1)
full_set = set(full_list)
if set1.issubset(full_set):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Comment: We have to convert list to tuples first, as they aren't hashable.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a *function* to process all of these, all the mentioned methods will work, just displaying other options, you could use `filter` and compare the `lens` as well

```
def is_in_full(k):
    l = list(filter(lambda x: x in k, full_list))
    if len(l) == len(k):
        return 'Yes'
    else:
        return 'No'

print(is_in_full(find1))
# Yes
```